# 'git pull' updating files but no changes on the actual website

Tags: git, ubuntu, mern

I'm working with MERN stack right now and pulled everything up on the Ubuntu server. So when I'm trying to update with `git pull` everything seems fine, files are updating but nothing changed on the website.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain how things are organized at the server and why do you expect `git pull` to update anything on the website?

Comment: You're mixing git pull and push.

Answer (score 2):

`git pull` pulls things from the server to your local computer. To send things from your local computer to the server, you use `git push`. For more information about git push, check out [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Comment: I don't know but changes applied when I reset git 
'git reset --hard HEAD'
And every time I pull changes I need to reset git with this command